# join and select operation on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, normalization, foreign-key-relationship

i got two tables like

```
table1
=======
id   primary
sku
price
vendor

table2
=====
id    primary
sku
alt_sku
```

basically, my search term will be sku or alt_sku, and based on it, I want to select data from table1

what will be best approach to do this? should I create a third table to store relation between table1.sku and table2.sku /table2.alt_sku?? or how can I get data from table1

sorry, if this question is veryy foolish...I am trying to learn mysql, so for, I was on WP and never went to basics

Comment: What is the relation between the two tables?

Comment: column 'id' is primary key in both

Comment: I meant how they are relates to each others?

Comment: if data in your tables are independent and only sometimes can cross over - I would suggest using link table.. (to store relations between two tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an [inner join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp). Assuming `TERM` is the sku you are searching for.

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2 on (t1.sku = t2.sku)
WHERE
     t1.sku = 'TERM'
  or t2.alt_sku = 'TERM'
```

Comment: -1. Because the OP asked "what will be best approach to do this", this is not the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do with Table2?  Perhaps a better approach would be the following:

```
Table1 
   id
   price
   vendor

Table2
   Table1Id
   Sku
```

That way you can store a 1-N number of SKUs associated with Table1.  If you only want 2 potential SKUs, then you could add a SkuType field to your Table2 - 1 for Primary and 2 for Alternate, but that may be going too deep for your needs...

And to query:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Table1 T
   JOIN Table2 T2 ON T.Id = T2.Table1Id
WHERE T2.Sku = 'SomeSku'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your table structure should be like that:

```
table1
=======
id   primary
IdFromtable2
price
vendor

table2
=====
id    primary
sku
alt_sku
```

Your Select Query will be like:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.IdFromtable2 = t2.Id
WHERE  t2.sku = @sku AND
       t2.alt_sku  = @alt_sku
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically,The finger rule for table relationships is as following:

If the relations is `one-to-many` then you should save the PK from the `many` table as additional column in the `one` table.

If the relations is `many-to-many` you should create a third table (connecting table). This table will have both PK from both tables (for each tbl1 PK you will have all tbl2 PK's and vice versa).

That way you preventing duplicated records.